# setup schema in databricks with location using service principal

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hive, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I am using Azure Databricks using a cluster (LTS 13.3) **without** Credential Passthrough and based on service principals only.

The goal is to create a schema using a location option on adls (using abfss protocol) so that I can create delta table which gets registered in the catalog and the underlying data gets saved in the specified location.

I am able to read and write data to adls storage account using service principals as expected -

```py
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net", "relevant_vals")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net", "relevant_vals")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/relevant_vals/oauth2/token")
```

However, when I try to create the schema -

```
%sql
CREATE schema my_new_schema LOCATION "abfss://testingcontainer@MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net/my_new_schema.db"
```

I get this error -

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException Failure to initialize configuration for storage account MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key)
```

I do not have any issues reading or writing data to adls using the service principals. It feels like the issue is with registering the schema/tables in the default metastore?
If I create the schema with credential passthrough (as my id has access) I am able to create the schema.. but writing data fails with the error

```py
df.write.format('delta')\
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("path","abfss://testingcontainer@MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net/my_new_schema.db/table_test_copy_v20240307.delta")\
.saveAsTable('my_new_schema.table_test_copy_v20240307')
```

fails with :

```
Failure to initialize configuration for storage account MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

Can someone please help me understand what is the issue and how I can register schema and tables in the databricks hive metastore while specifying location on adls using service principals? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message:

```
Failure to initialize configuration for storage account MyStorageAcct.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

When using the **abfss** protocol, you cannot directly use a storage account **SAS** token to access data. When using the abfss protocol, you cannot utilize a storage account access key to access data. To use abfss, you must provide additional configuration options, as detailed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly).

Using a storage access key is only recommended when using the `wasbs` protocol, but it is not advisable for use with ADLS Gen2. Additionally, if you have the necessary permissions, you can utilize a [passthrough cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough) to access the storage account.

To create a table in a blob folder location and store the table on an external location.

**Set the Variables:**

```
catalog_name = test_catalog
schema_name = test_schema
catalog_container = <catalog container string>
storage_account = <storage account string>
blob_path = f"abfss://{catalog_container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder path>"
```

**Create Catalog:**

```
spark.sql(f"CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS {catalog_name} MANAGED LOCATION 'abfss://{catalog_container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/'")
```

**Create Schema:**

```
spark.sql(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {catalog_name}.{schema_name}")
```

**References:** MS [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1314651/error-invalid-configuration-value-detected-for-fs)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825487/error-invalid-configuration-value-detected-for-fs-azure-account-key) Link.